# why is my analysis for this resistor \$R_F\$ feedback network different from the book answer?

Tags: feedback

The following is from the book  [Design of Analog CMOS Integrated Circuit](https://electrovolt.ir/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Design-of-Analog-CMOS-Integrated-Circuit-2nd-Edition-ElectroVolt.ir_.pdf), page 313.

Calculate the voltage gain of the circuit. (channel length modulation and bulk effect are neglected)

[image]

At Node X with the help of KCL.

$$\frac{V_{in} - V_x} {R_S} = \frac{V_x - V_{out}} {R_F}$$

$$\Rightarrow V_x = \frac{V_{in} R_F + V_{out} R_S} {R_F + R_S}$$

At node \$V_{out}\$ with the help of KCL.

$$\frac{V_x - V_{out}} {R_F} - \frac{V_{out}} {R_D} = V_x g_{m}$$

So the gain will look like this when we subsitute \$\frac{V_{in} R_F + V_{out} R_S} {R_F + R_S}\$ for \$V_x\$.

$$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{(1 - g_m R_F) R_D} {R_D + R_F + R_S + R_D R_S g_m}$$

However, the book give the following.

$$\frac{V_{out}} {V_{in}} = \frac{1} {R_S} \cdot \frac{-(R_S \parallel R_F) g_m (R_F \parallel R_D)} {1  + g_m (R_F \parallel R_D) R_S / (R_S + R_F)} 
 = \frac{- g_m R_F^2 R_D} {R_F R_S + R_D R_F + R_D R_S + R_F^2 + g_m R_F R_D R_S}$$

Comment: Simply the author is using a different approach. And your answer gives the exact solution. However, the author's answer does not give the exact solution compared to your solution.

Comment: @G36 Thank you very much!